# Calling an image using ACF Select Field Type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am running Advanced Custom Fields on a Wordpress build and I added a *Select* Field Type to image attachments. The *Field Name* is `image_category` and I have three selections: `top`, `middle`, `bottom`. These images will be called around multiple parts of the site in different iterations. Some sections have multiple images that I want to show together but should be ordered randomly. In the bottom example, I am only calling one image that has the category `bottom` selected. This doesn't seem to find the image however, could this be a field issue? I haven't figured out how to call these images using the `$get_field()` function which in my head, seems easier than taxonomies? Any help is much appreciated!

```
<?php // Get Banner Advertisement Posts
$banneradverts = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_status'       => 'any',
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'image_category',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'bottom',
            ),
        ),
    );
$banners = new WP_Query( $banneradverts );

while ( $banners->have_posts() ) : $banners->the_post();?>
<section id="bottom">
    <div class="bottom-image">
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'full'); ?>
    </div>
</section>          
<?php endwhile;     
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you created the post_type 'attachment' yourself? Or are you trying to retrieve a specific attachment from WordPress?

Comment: just trying to get any image that has 'bottom' selected in the 'image_category' field name

Comment: OK. Since 'image_category' is a custom field, you need to do a 'meta_query' instead of a 'tax_query'. Do you need help with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_status'       => 'any',
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'meta_key'          => 'image_category',
    'meta_value'        => 'bottom',
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<section id="bottom">
    <div class="bottom-image">
        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), 'full'); ?>
    </div>
</section>          
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```